# Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Can anyone explain what is theses errors?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set
>   property 'innerHTML' of null
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'style' of null
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   ILLEGAL
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object #
>   has no method 'dispatchEvent'

This is my test [Website](http://www.westportugal.com/product_info.php/c/8_14/i/26/formacao/subcategoria-1/artigo-1)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the firebug error console for details on these messages?

Comment: Really should try to post at least some code for review rather than just an external link to some site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some point in the page you have:

```
function display_price(price, oid)
{
    ...

    element = document.getElementById(oid);
    if (valor != 'NaN' && valor != null && valor != '')
    {
       element.innerHTML = valor + money_simbol;
```

The last line is causing the error because `element` is null. You should add a condition to the if(): that is, change this line:

```
if (valor != 'NaN' && valor != null && valor != '')
```

to this:

```
if (element && valor != 'NaN' && valor != null && valor != '')
```

In other words, it's a good practice to *always* check the return value of a function *before* accessing its properties.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function `display_price` passing it ID of `span` that does not yet exist.

Change this line: (appears twice in your code)

```
display_price('510', 'products_price_id');
```

To this instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
   display_price('510', 'products_price_id');
};
```

This will wait until the page loads before trying to find the element, thus solve your errors.